# Disabled space caused by validator in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I got multiple `TextFormField` widgets. The problem is when the user doesn't meet some of the requirements while filling the form , some error message will pop under the `TextFormField` .

The problem is that the error text is causing too much space between the widgets.

How can I reduce the amount of that space ?

```
    TextFormField buildConformPassFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => conform_password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.isNotEmpty && password == conform_password) {
          removeError(error: kMatchPassError);
        }
        conform_password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return ""; // THIS IS WHAT CAUSING THE WHITE SPACE.
        } else if ((password != value)) {
          addError(error: kMatchPassError);
          return ""; // THIS IS WHAT CAUSING THE WHITE SPACE.
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Confirmez le mot de passe",
        hintText: "Re-entrez le mot de passe",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return null, remove all `return "";` from the `validator`

Comment: Yes , but I want to show the error but with less amount of space.

Comment: Can you please clarify what does the addError method do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

share screen shoot of current output when error show's.
in general, try to add `errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0.7)`, to `InputDecoration`.